# Refresh Postgres Materialized view after calling Spring JPA save()

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In a spring boot application which uses JpaRepositories, if I refresh a Postgres' materialized view immediately after calling `repository.save(entity)`, will the view contain new entities?

In a code like this:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService {
    private final MyRepository repository

    @Transactional
    public Collection<FooEntity> updateDatabaseEntries() {
        // ...
        val saved = repository.saveAll(dataRecords);
        repository.refreshMyView();
        return saved;
    }
}
```

and Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<FooEntity, UUID> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW myView", nativeQuery = true)
    void refreshMyView();
}
```

and a view which accesses Foo entities, for example:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW myView AS SELECT * from foo;
```

Will `myView` always contain data saved with `saveAll` in the `updateDatabaseEntries` method?

Comment: From my tests it seems to be true, but I'd love to have a confirmation from SO JPA experts.